# How to write an if-then statement in LaTeX using the value of an R variable in knitr/Sweave

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I am currently using knitr along with R 3.0.2 and RStudio in order to produce a LaTeX report. My report is typed up as a .Rnw file, and compiled using the knit2pdf function.

I would like to use an [if-then formulation in LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/if) in order to create a separate section, but have the if-then condition use the value of a variable from R (let's call it `CreateOptionalSection`).

Is this possible? If so, how can I refer to the R variable in the .tex document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{comment}` to the preamble of your latex file.

At the line before the optional section starts, do

```
<<startcomment, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
if(!CreateOptionalSection){
  cat("\\begin{comment}")
}
@
```

At the line after the optional section ends, do

```
<<endcomment, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
if(!CreateOptionalSection){
  cat("\\end{comment}")
}
@
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it directly in `R` code in your `.Rnw` file, using `cat` to paste the section. Here is an example, when `x > 0` it creates `section 1`, when `x < 0` it creates `section 2`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<condition, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
x<- rnorm(1)
if(x>0){
  text <- "\\section{Section 1}
  This is new section 1"
  }else{
  text <- "\\section{Section 2}
  This is new section 2"
  }
@
Testing the code: the result of x (which here was \Sexpr{x}) will determine the section.
<<print, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
cat(text)
@

\end{document}
```

This will give you:
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this solution so that \Sexpr{x} was included in the text variable? Thank you. I posted a similar question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492667/if-else-statement-in-knitr-sweave-using-r-variable-as-conditional