# If-Else Statement in knitr/Sweave using R variable as conditional

Tags: r, if-statement, knitr, sweave

I am currently using knitr in R and RStudio to produce a LaTeX output. My code is a .Rnw file (called, say, testKnitr.Rnw) that is compiled to a pdf file with:

```
knit("testKnitr.Rnw") // in RStudio
pdflatex testKnitr.tex // in terminal
```

I would like to use an if-else syntax in LaTeX so that, depending on the value of an R variable, one of two LaTeX text paragraphs are output. In these LaTeX paragraphs, I would like to use expressions like \Sexpr{} and and \ref.

I have a minimal-working-example that is based on the second answer to a similar question posted here:

[How to write an if-then statement in LaTeX using the value of an R variable in knitr/Sweave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305444/how-to-write-an-if-then-statement-in-latex-using-the-value-of-an-r-variable-in-k)

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(
concordance=TRUE
)
@

<<condition, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
x<- rnorm(1)
if(x>0){
  text <- "This means x value of \Sexpr{x} was greater than 0"
  }else{
  text <- "This means x value of \Sexpr{x} was less than 0"
  }
@

Testing the code: 

<<print, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
cat(text)
@

\end{document}
```

Ideally, the intended output of the above MWE would a report with one line that contained something like:

```
"This means x value of 0.87 was greater than 0"
```

or

```
"This means x value of -0.87 was less than 0"
```

Comment: You could include the value in the output with `text <- paste("This means x value of", x, "was greater than 0")`. Would that not work in your non-minimal case?

Comment: Thank you @DavidRobinson. I might have to create a better MWE! Because, I am trying to get LaTeX syntax like \Sexpr{} and \ref{} into the text. So, I don't think your solution could work for something like \ref{}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before answering this question, I would like to take a look at the meta-question of whether this *should* be done.

### Should we do it?

I don't think so. What we are basically doing here is using `knitr` to insert `\Sexpr{x}` in a document and then interpret `\Sexpr{x}`. There are no (obvious) reasons why we should take this detour instead of inserting the value of `x` directly to the document.

### How to do it?

The following minimal example shows how it could be done anyways:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<setup, echo = FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
knit_patterns$set(header.begin = NULL)
@

<<condition, echo=FALSE>>=
x <- rnorm(1)
if (x > 0) {
  text <- "This means x value of \\Sexpr{x} was greater than 0"
  } else {
    text <- "This means x value of \\Sexpr{x} was less than 0"
  }
@

Testing the code:

<<print, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
cat(text)
@

\end{document}
```

Two things are important here:

- We need to escape the backslash in `\Sexpr`, resulting in `\Sexpr`.
- We need to set `knit_patterns$set(header.begin = NULL)`.

To compile the document:

- Save it as `doc.Rnw`.
- Then execute:

  ```
  knitEnv <- new.env()
  knit(input = "doc.Rnw", output = "intermediate.Rnw", envir = knitEnv)
  knit2pdf(input = "intermediate.Rnw", output = "doc_final.tex", envir = knitEnv)
  ```

#### What happens?

The first call of `knit` generates `intermediate.Rnw` with the following content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Testing the code:

This means x value of \Sexpr{x} was less than 0

\end{document}
```

You should note that `knitr` didn't include any definitions, commands etc. as usual to the LaTeX code. This is due to setting `header.begin = NULL` and documented [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/patterns/). We need this behavior because we want to knit the resulting document *again* in the second step and LaTeX doesn't like it when the same stuff is defined twice.

Creating the new environment `knitEnv` and setting it as `envir` is optional. If we skip this, the variable `x` will be created in the global environment.

In the second step we use `knit2pdf` to knit `intermediate.Rnw` and immediately generate a PDF afterwards. If `envir` was used in the first step, we need to use it here too. This is how `x` and it's value are conveyed from the first to the second knitting step.

This time all the gory LaTeX stuff is included and we get `doc_final.tex` with:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
%% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
%% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

%% more gory stuff %%


\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\begin{document}

Testing the code:

This means x value of \ensuremath{-0.294859} was less than 0

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @user2706569 for your detailed post! Sometimes, when I create MWE, in an attempt to remove superfluous information, I inadvertently remove important information. In this case, I believe I removed the information on *why* we should do it. Really, I am also doing things not just \Sexpr{}, but also with \ref{}. That is why (I believe) I cannot just print the value of the variable in \Sexpr{}, because it would not solve \ref{}.

Comment: I don't think that \Sexpr and \ref are comparable. \ref is a LaTeX command and is resolved during compilation (TEX --> PDF).

Comment: Thank you, @user2706569. I have been very poor at figuring out when certain syntax are compiled, but I appreciate your explanation. I posted a similar question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505959/if-else-statement-in-knitr-sweave-using-r-variable-as-conditional-part-2) in case anyone is interested. I have MWE using both \Sexpr and \ref there, that hopefully does not over-simplify what I am trying to do the most efficient way. Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding the syntax: Usually everything with `\command{}` is LaTeX. `\Sexpr` is a nasty exception. I'll have a look at the other question later.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought \command{} was usually LaTeX, and was pretty confused to learn that \Sexpr is not. Relieved to know it is an exception!