# If-Else Statement in knitr/Sweave using R variable as conditional (Part 2)

Tags: r, if-statement, latex, knitr, sweave

I am extending a question I posted here:

[If-Else Statement in knitr/Sweave using R variable as conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492667/if-else-statement-in-knitr-sweave-using-r-variable-as-conditional)

I would like to use an if-else syntax in LaTeX so that, depending on the value of an R variable (say x), one of two LaTeX text paragraphs are output. If x>0, then the LaTeX paragraph has a figure and a table. However, if x<0, then the LaTeX paragraph has just a figure (and no table).

I have a MWE that works and is based on the checked answer at the previous post:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,nohyper]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

<<setup, echo = FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
library(ggplot2)
knit_patterns$set(header.begin = NULL)
@

<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
fname="myOutput.pdf"
pdf(fname,width=4,height=4)
print(qplot(mpg,cyl,data=mtcars))
{dev.off();invisible()}
cat(sprintf('\\begin{marginfigure}
\\includegraphics[width=0.98\\linewidth]{%s}
\\caption{\\label{mar:dataMtcars}Comments about mtcar dataset.}
\\end{marginfigure}',sub('\\.pdf','',fname)))
@

<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
x<- rnorm(1)
if (x>0){
  myDF = data.frame(a=rnorm(1:5),b=rnorm(1:5),c=rnorm(1:5))
  print(xtable(myDF,caption='Data frame comments', label='tab:myDataFrame'),floating=FALSE, tabular.environment = "longtable",include.rownames=FALSE)
}
@

<<condition, echo=FALSE>>=
if(x>0){
  text <- "Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \\Sexpr{x} was greater than 0. Table \\ref{tab:myDataFrame} shows my data frame."
  }else{
  text <- "Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \\Sexpr{x} was less than 0. We do not show a data frame."
  }
@

Testing the code: 

<<print, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
cat(text)
@

\end{document}
```

I then save this MWE as something like testKnitr.Rnw, and run:

```
knit(input = "testKnitr.Rnw", output = "intermediate.Rnw")
knit2pdf(input = "intermediate.Rnw", output = "doc_final.tex")
```

I am wondering if I am creating this code efficiently, especially because it was pointed out to me in my previous post that - in the case of just using \Sexpr{} - there were easier solutions. It is a bit cumbersome to knit twice here.

Is there an easier way to incorporate my if/else statement to display one of two paragraphs containing the variable value, figures, and/or tables, all based on the value of the variable? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to the [related question that has been linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492667/if-else-statement-in-knitr-sweave-using-r-variable-as-conditional) dynamically generating `\Sexpr{}` and parsing the intermediate output a second time is not necessary in this scenario.

Many things happen in the code from the question, but this is the key chunk (where `x` gets a random value assigned in a previous chunk):

```
<<condition, echo=FALSE>>=
if (x > 0) {
  text <- "Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \\Sexpr{x} was greater than 0. Table \\ref{tab:myDataFrame} shows my data frame."
  } else {
    text <- "Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \\Sexpr{x} was less than 0. We do not show a data frame."
    }
@
```

### Direct substitutes for `print`ing `\Sexpr`

Straighforward alternatives to `\Sexpr{}` are `paste` and `sprintf` (I use one in the `if` branch and one in the `else` branch just for demonstration):

```
<<condition, echo=FALSE>>=
if (x > 0) {
  text <- paste("Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of", x, "was greater than 0. Table \\ref{tab:myDataFrame} shows my data frame.")
  } else {
    text <- sprintf("Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of %f was less than 0. We do not show a data frame.", x)
    }
@
```

This works well when the text to be conditionally displayed is not too long. Otherwise, it might be more convenient to use LaTeX `if`-statements. This has the advantage that not too much code is wrapped in characer strings / code chunks. Then, `\Sexpr{}` might again be useful.

### Using LaTeX conditional expressions

There are [many ways to write conditional expressions in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5896/37118), but the most simple form will be enough.

- First, define a new `if` that we'll call `ifPositive`:
  `\newif\ifPositive`.
- Second, use R to insert `\Positivetrue` or
  `\Positivefalse` into the document.
- Third, use `\ifPositive … \else … \fi`.

  ```
  \newif\ifPositive

  <<condtion2, echo = FALSE, results = "asis">>=
  if (x > 0) {
    cat("\\Positivetrue")
  } else {
    cat("\\Positivefalse")
  }
  @

  \ifPositive
  Figure \ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \Sexpr{x} was greater than 0. Table \ref{tab:myDataFrame} shows my data frame.
  \else
  Figure \ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \Sexpr{x} was less than 0. We do not show a data frame.
  \fi
  ```

### Other remarks

In the question there is a chunk that generates `myOutput.pdf`. There, `pdf()` and `dev.off()` are used. This is no good style and [kills kittens](http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/). There is no need to bypass `knitr`'s mechanisms for producing plots; not even when custom environments like `marginfigure` instead of `figure` are to be used. The chunk should be replaced by something like this:

```
<<dataMtcars, echo=FALSE, fig.env = "marginfigure", out.width = "0.98\\linewidth", fig.cap = "Comments about mtcar dataset.", fig.lp = "mar:">>=
print(qplot(mpg,cyl,data=mtcars))
@
```

`fig.lp = "mar:"` is only necessary in order to produce the exactly same label as in the question `mar:dataMtcars`. It could be skipped if the label `fig:dataMtcars` was also okay.

### Document

Finally, here the complete document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,nohyper]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

<<setup, echo = FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
library(ggplot2)
@

<<dataMtcars, echo=FALSE, fig.env = "marginfigure", out.width = "0.98\\linewidth", fig.cap = "Comments about mtcar dataset.", fig.lp = "mar:">>=
print(qplot(mpg,cyl,data=mtcars))
@

<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
x <- rnorm(1)
if (x > 0) {
  myDF <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1:5), b = rnorm(1:5), c = rnorm(1:5))
  print(xtable(myDF, caption= 'Data frame comments', label='tab:myDataFrame'), floating = FALSE, tabular.environment = "longtable", include.rownames=FALSE)
}
@

<<condition, echo=FALSE>>=
if (x > 0) {
  text <- paste("Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of", x, "was greater than 0. Table \\ref{tab:myDataFrame} shows my data frame.")
  } else {
    text <- sprintf("Figure \\ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of %f was less than 0. We do not show a data frame.", x)
    }
@

  Testing the code:

<<print, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
  cat(text)
@

\paragraph{Alternative:}

\newif\ifPositive

<<condtion2, echo = FALSE, results = "asis">>=
if (x > 0) {
  cat("\\Positivetrue")
} else {
  cat("\\Positivefalse")
}
@

\ifPositive
Figure \ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \Sexpr{x} was greater than 0. Table \ref{tab:myDataFrame} shows my data frame.
\else
Figure \ref{mar:dataMtcars} shows the mtcars data set. The x value of \Sexpr{x} was less than 0. We do not show a data frame.
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Incredibly helpful! Thank you.